# Obtain field value from array in Firestore using python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this structure in my Firestore database.

[image: structure]

So, I need to know how to obtain the field value from one of the fields in the array, for example, "numeroPoliza".

Someone did do it before using python?

I tried with some examples, but no one works well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "I tried with some examples, but no one works well" Without seeing what you already tried, it is unlikely that anyone can explain it better than the Firebase documentation already does, e.g. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#python. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there gives you the best chance that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think there is no better solution than:

First, **get the whole field** containing the array (here: `'polizias'`), or even the whole file.

And then, do whatever you want in your code with this array, which became a **Python list**.

---

Example:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate(_auth_data)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

# doc is a DocumentReference
doc = db.collection('MyCollection').document('MyDoc')

# first get() returns a DocumentSnapshot, second returns any field
polizas = doc.get().get('polizas')

# polizas now is a list of dicts
# read any field or iterate as you want
print(polizas[0]['numeroPoliza'])
for pol in polizas:
    print(pol['numeroPoliza'])
```